# Facebook Cant get /me/likes data for part of users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is the simplest application that can be made:

```
<?php
include_once "inc/fb/facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => 'xxx',
    'secret'    => 'yyy'
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump( $facebook->api("/me/likes/") );
?>`
```

In return I should get an array of pages, that user have already liked. The problem is, that it doesnt work for some users.
Somehow in a process, I have found that error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in (...)/fb/base_facebook.php on line 1039
```

I have tryed to force the get token with:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

and it gests the token for every user, but still no table about what user likes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the user_likes permission from those users, and are you sure your token hasn't expired?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite simple:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope'         => 'publish_stream,user_about_me',
'redirect_uri'  => $mySettings->app_url,
));
echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>";
```

I have forgoten about user_likes permission in scope. But what is strange to me - why did it worked for most of the users?